# How can I stop the Tumblr HTML post editor from putting <p> tags around my YouTube embeds?

Tags: tumblr

I’m trying to embed a YouTube video in a Tumblr text post. I would use the Tumblr video post type, but that doesn’t give the post a title. I’ve pasted in the YouTube embed HTML into my post, using the HTML editing mode of Tumblr’s post editing textbox.

When I publish the post to my Tumblr, it puts `<p>` tags around YouTube’s embed code. This causes some style issues, and incidentally is invalid HTML.

How can I stop the `<p>` tags being inserted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to switch from the editor that you're using to one that allows you better control of the HTML.

> Account > Preferences > Edit posts using > plain text/HTML

If you were using the rich text editor it would have automatically put in those `<P>` tags no matter how many times you edit them out.

Switching to another editor will give you the ability to now post without extraneous tags being put into your tumblr posts.

Comment: Tremendous, cheers. (No idea why I didn’t think to look in the preferences; I guess as most of Tumblr’s options seem to be right there next to the thing you’re trying to work with, I assumed this would be the same.)